# Django - how to run background script in loop

Tags: django, background-task, teamspeak

I have install django 3.0 and I want to add on website bot which will listen for events in background, manage server and users. Bot is dedicated for teamspeak application, using https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-ts3/tree/v2

simple code:

```
import time
import ts3

with ts3.query.TS3ServerConnection("telnet://localhost:25639") as ts3conn:
        ts3conn.exec_("auth", apikey="AAAA-....-EEEE")

        # Register for events
        ts3conn.exec_("clientnotifyregister", event="any", schandlerid=0)

        while True:
                event = ts3conn.wait_for_event()
                print(event.parsed)
```

How can I run this in django background, I have try add code with asyncio to manage.py but teamspeak bot connect to server and website doesn't work
Shoud I use Celery, django-background-task or just add it as app, how to manage events received by bot in django?

Comment: Well, you'd normally use `django-workers` or `channels` =>https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html but I think in this case the Celery is probably the way to go, since it's the most robust.

Comment: Could you provide me some informations about how to intergrate that kind of app with Celery in django? I hear that long running process in django can be problematic and Celery is the best solution

Comment: For a simple  solution, try adding your code in cron jobs and schedule it as you want.

Comment: as you see, script need to work in loop to listen for events on server, it cant be running by cronjob, even I run it via cronjob it will be separately process, how to manage events between django and this bot process